# Bundle react in an external file with browserify

Tags: gulp, browserify, babeljs

So I have seen this question answered several different ways but I can't seem to get it to work. The bundle I make seems to work except it sticks react inside thus making it duplicated since its also in vendor.js.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify = require('browserify');



gulp.task('default', function() {

  // app
    var appBundler = browserify({
        entries: ['./client/main.js'],
    transform: [['babelify', {"presets": ['es2015', 'react']}]]
    })

  appBundler.external('react')

  appBundler.bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public'))

  // vendors
  browserify({
      debug: true,
      require: ['react']
  }).bundle()
    .pipe(source('vendors.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public'))

});
```

Comment: which version of react are you using?

Comment: That looks like it should work. Does your app bundle require in any other React packages, like `react-addons-*`?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can't split off react w/o react-dom if you're using it. Turns out my problem was fixed by also adding react-dom to my externals

```
appBundler.external(['react', 'react-dom'])
```

My super simple hello world example did import "react-dom."  :\

Thanks for the help! These questions prompted me to dig a little deeper into versions and imports and led me to my answer :)